# Select all rows by group with condition

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
`dat <- data.frame(date = c("2017-02-23", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-05","2018-05-23", "2018-02-22"), grp = c(1,1,6,7,7,7), 
var2 = c(1,3,18,15,25,5))`
```

I would like to have all the rows of each group (grp) when value of var2>=14

Expected results:

```
    dat <- data.frame(date = c("2017-02-15", "2017-02-05","2018-05-23", 
"2018-02-22"), grp = c(6,7,7,7), var2 = c(18,15,25,5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe without groupby , with base R

```
dat[dat$grp %in% dat$grp [dat$var2 >= 14],]
        date grp var2
3 2017-02-15   6   18
4 2017-02-05   7   15
5 2018-05-23   7   25
6 2018-02-22   7    5
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `any` in `filter` after grouping by 'grp'

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    filter(any(var2 >= 14))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   grp [2]
#  date         grp  var2
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2017-02-15     6    18
#2 2017-02-05     7    15
#3 2018-05-23     7    25
#4 2018-02-22     7     5
```

Or with `all` on reverse logic

```
dat %>% 
   group_by(grp) %>% 
   filter(!all(var2 < 14))
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `ave` to create a logical vector for subsetting the rows

```
dat[with(dat, ave(var2 >= 14, grp, FUN = any)),]
```

Comment: I learned something new today! Thanks for showing me `any()`. :)